# Angular 6 lazy loading problem with routes

Tags: angular, typescript

I want use lazy loading in your app. A have 2 modules: login and cars. Lazy loading is working fine, but route /add-car not working. Why?
Path /add-car is not found and redirect to PageNotFoundComponent.

app.routing.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'login'
    },
    {
        path: 'cars',
        canLoad: [AuthCanLoadGuard],
        loadChildren: './cars/cars.module#CarsModule',
    },
    {
        path: 'user-account',
        component: UserAccountComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardsService]
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {enableTracing: true})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
```

cars.routing.module.ts

```
const carsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: CarsComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: CarsListComponent,
                resolve: { cars : CarsListResolve } // przeniesione z app.routing.module.ts
            },
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: CarsDetailsComponent,
                canDeactivate: [FormCanDeactivateGuard],
                resolve: { car: CarResolve }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '/add-car',
        component: AddCarComponent,

    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(carsRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be redirecting to `cars/add-car` since add-car is the part of `cars.routing.module.ts`; Also when you route, make sure to use  `{ relativeTo: this.route }`.
Ex: `this.router.navigate(['../add-car'], { relativeTo: this.route });`

Answer (score 2):

Path cannot start with a slash. Adjust `/add-car` to `add-car`:

```
{
        path: 'add-car',
        component: AddCarComponent,

    }
```

And, as mentioned in the answer above, you'll also need the `/cars` context. As `add-car` is a child, it is only available under `/cars`, so path you'd use is in the browser is `/cars/add-cars`

Answer (score 0):

If I can get /car-add path I should add this path in app.routing.module.ts?
It will be correct add addCarComponent outside cars module?